# Last Row of Listview overlaped by the Footer of parent Layout

Tags: android, listview, scroll, android-edittext

I am trying to create a UI in which there is an `EditText` below the `listview`. When I add rows of the `listview` the last row stays under the editText and user is unable to see it unless he drag the list upward manually. I want this to happen programatically but unable to do so..
So far I have tried this

```
    list_con.post(new Runnable(){
                  public void run() {
                      list_con.setSelection(list_con.getCount());
                  }});
```

as soon as I add a row, I tried to programatically scroll it down.But the last row overlapping with the `edittext` is still there
EDIT:

my layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:textColor="#fafafa"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="390dip"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/lay1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dip"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerlayout"
        android:background="#00000A"
        android:stackFromBottom="true" />
<!--          android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll -->
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/footerlayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:weightSum="3">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textbox"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:background="@drawable/textbox2"
         android:gravity="top|left"
        android:hint="Type to text" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/send2323"
    android:gravity="center" 

    android:text="SEND"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    />

 </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post code to your layout here, it looks like a layout problem.